# Html card scroll bar

Tags: html, angular

I'm working on an angular app and the UI has several `.card` blocks, but as I keep adding them to the Html, they disappear in the bottom of the page, I was expecting that as I keep adding them a scroll bar would appear in the page, could someone help me with that?

```
<div class="content-area">
<div class="clr-row">
    <div class="clr-col-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
                <div class="card-title" *ngIf="project">
                    <app-shr-project-header [project]='project'></app-shr-project-header>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clr-row" style="margin-top: 24px;">
    <div class="clr-col-12">
        <app-submission-review-grid></app-submission-review-grid>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clr-row">
    <div class="clr-col-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
                <div class="card-title">
                    <h4>
                        Information Requests
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-text">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clr-row">
    <div class="clr-col-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
                <div class="card-title">
                    <h4>
                        Attachments
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-text">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

the `main-container` is in another component

```
<div class="main-container">
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: You could set a fixed width to your card container - this will force it to scroll. (Assuming you are allowing for scrolling in the parent container)

Comment: @alpharomeo I tried `<div class="content-area" style="height: 200px"` and didn't work, in the other HTML files that I've worked I just kept adding general content and the Html by itself puts the scroll bar if necessary, also in other views, I don't see they put something in particular for the scroll

Comment: Try width instead of height and set important. Then inspect in inspector that nothing is overriding your definition.

Comment: @alpharomeo with `width` I'm able to modify the width but I'm referring to the vertical scroll, that's why I put `height` before, but I still gave it a try, and didn't worked

Comment: @alpharomeo I just change the whole Html code, copy-pasting another view that has de vertical scroll and didn't work, most be another thing then

Answer (score 0):

Ok even though my `app.component` already has a `class="main-container`, putting another one to this Html, also I was missing the `class="content-container"`, with these two now is working

```
<div class="main-container">
<div class="content-container">
    <div class="content-area">
        <h1>
            SHPO Response
        </h1>
        <div class="content-area">
            <div class="clr-row">
                <div class="clr-col-lg-12">
                    <div class="card mt-0">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <div class="card-title" *ngIf="project">
                                <app-shr-project-header [project]='project'></app-shr-project-header>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="clr-row" style="margin-top: 24px;">
                <div class="clr-col-12">
                    <app-submission-review-grid></app-submission-review-grid>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="clr-row">
                <div class="clr-col-lg-12">
                    <div class="card mt-0">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <div class="card-title">
                                <h4>
                                    Information Requests
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-text">
                                ...
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="clr-row">
                <div class="clr-col-lg-12">
                    <div class="card mt-0">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <div class="card-title">
                                <h4>
                                    Attachments
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-text">
                                ...
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```